# R Markdown / Bookdown: How to custom number book chapters?

Tags: markdown, bookdown

For example, instead of
ch.1 - intro
ch.2 - experiment
ch.3 - format
ch.4 - conclusions ...

to have:
ch.0 - intro
ch.1 - experiment
ch.-1 - format
ch.2 - conclusions ...

I know that in latex you can use \setcounter{chapter}{-2} to have the next chapter be Ch. -1, and achieve custom chapter numbering. I am looking for similar functionality within R Markdown / Bookdown, and have not been able to find it.  The hope is to easily export the markdown with custom chapters to epub, pdf, and html using bookdown.

(My current workaround is to have all of the chapters be un-numbered, and include the chapter number in the title, though the formatting is sub-optimal.)

Comment: I use Bookdown too but find the website/book (https://bookdown.org/) is Never Explicit enough for me...